# C# static List<> has item but cannot access it

Tags: c#, static

Following NullReferenceException throws when ChildFolders() gets called. In the bottom of the picture, one can see that at least one desired Folder exists. But trying to access them doesnt work. How does this happen?

[image: Following NullReferenceException]

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: You error is very clear. The folder is not instantiated

Comment: Your list of folders contains null.

Comment: How to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please paste your code, and the type and message from exceptions, into your question as text. It's hardly convenient for us to squint at an enormous blacked-out screenshot with a small amount of relevant information scattered here and there.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the null-conditional operator

```
return Folders.FindAll(x => x?.ParentFolderID == parentFolderId);
```